# created a simple BREAKOUT game with jquery, attempting to convert back to plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, breakout

I created breakout using some jquery and a handy tutorial online.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/9bLEk/6/

I successfully changed the WIDTH and HEIGHT accessing the window size like this:

From:

```
WIDTH = $("#canvas")[0].width = $(window).width();
HEIGHT = $("#canvas")[0].height = $(window).height();
```

To:

```
var WIDTH  = document.getElementById("canvas");
var HEIGHT  = document.getElementById("canvas");

WIDTH.width = window.innerWidth;
HEIGHT.height = window.innerHeight;
WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
```

the code loads properly. I am finding a problem changing the code that renders the ball.
It works with jquery here:

```
Cir = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

Cir.beginPath();
Cir.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
Cir.closePath();
Cir.fill();
```

Does not work with:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var Cir = canvas.getContext("2d");

Cir.beginPath();
Cir.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
Cir.closePath();
Cir.fill();
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var Cir = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
```

Comment: maybe something conflicting somewhere else in my code.  I'll try figure it out thanks!

Comment: i cannot get the ball to render correctly without using jquery.  Could you take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/B77UB/1/